# Search large tar.gz file for keywords,copy and delete

Tags: python, bash, grep, tar

What is the best way with large log tar.gz files , some are 20 gig , to open and search for a keyword, copy found files to a directory , then delete the file so it doesn't consume disk space.
I have some code below, it was working but then it stopped extracting files suddenly for some reason. If i remove the -O option from tar it extracts files again.

```
mkdir -p found;
tar tf "$1" | while read -r FILE
do
    if tar xf "$1" "$FILE" -O  | grep -l "$2" ;then
        echo "found pattern in : $FILE";
        cp $FILE found/$(basename $FILE);
        rm -f $FILE;
    fi
done
```

$1 is the tar.gz file , $2 is the keyword

**UPDATE**

Im doing the below which works, but a small file i have has 2million plus compressed files, so will take hours to look at all the files.Is there a python solution or similar that can do it faster.

```
#!/bin/sh
# tarmatch.sh
if grep -l "$1" ; then 
  echo  "Found keyword in ${TAR_FILENAME}";
  tar -zxvf "$2" "${TAR_FILENAME}" 
else
  echo "Not found in ${TAR_FILENAME}";
fi
true

tar -zxf 20130619.tar.gz --to-command "./tarmatch.sh '@gmail' 20130619.tar.gz "
```

**UPDATE 2**

Im using python now and seems to of increased in speed, was doing about 4000 records a second while the bash version was doing about 5.Im not that strong in python so probably this code could be optimized, please let me know if this could be optimized.

```
import tarfile
import time
import os
import ntpath, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3 :
  print "Please provide the tar.gz file and keyword to search on"
  print "USAGE: tarfind.py example.tar.gz keyword"
  sys.exit() 

t = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1], 'r:gz')
cnt = 0;
foundCnt = 0;
now = time.time()
directory = 'found/'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

for tar_info in t:
    cnt+=1;
    if (tar_info.isdir()): continue
    if(cnt%1000 == 0): print "Processed " + str(cnt) + " files"
    f=t.extractfile(tar_info)
    if sys.argv[2] in f.read():
      foundCnt +=1
      newFile = open(directory + ntpath.basename(tar_info.name), 'w');
      f.seek(0,0)
      newFile.write( f.read() )
      newFile.close()
      print "found in file " + tar_info.name

future = time.time()
timeTaken = future-now

print "Found " + str(foundCnt) + " records"
print "Time taken " + str( int( timeTaken/60) ) + " mins " + str(int(timeTaken%60)) + " seconds"
print  str( int(cnt / timeTaken)) + " records per second"
t.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to search for a keyword in the files and extract only those, and since your file sizes are huge, it might take time if the keyword is somewhere at the middle.

The best advice I can give is probably use a powerful combination of a Inverted index lookup tool such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)(based on Lucene Indes) and [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/index.html) - a content analysis toolkit.

Using these tools you can index the tar.gz files and when you search for a keyword, relevant documents containig the keyword will be returned.

Comment: When i run the first line, it returns `-bash: -ztvf: command not found`

Comment: Ahh! Check now you need to do something like $(any_commond) to run that from the bash terminal or maybe you can put the commands in a script.

Comment: Replace your script accordingly with the above commands wherever applicable.

Comment: $file variable will contain you /path/to/file and then use tar -zxvf to extract a the file. Hope it helps.

Comment: @tsukimi: This should help you, I have added something more. I was little busy. Sorry that I messed up.

Comment: thanks updates. I think this searches for a keyword in a filename , i want to search inside the file and return the files that contain that keyword, there are thousands of files inside the tar.gz file

Comment: This is maybe an option in the future , but there is quite a lot o setup, the python script works for now

Comment: I think you should of left your original post and then updated , so these comments make sense! some of the other stuff you posted is stil useful

Comment: @tsukimi: Sorry I thought I had misunderstood the question, which I often usually do and edited it :( May be you can edit the answer again and add some relevant info from previous edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is really 20GB it will take very long to grep in any case. The only advice I can give is to use `zgrep`. This  will save you from having to explicitly uncompress the archive.

```
zgrep PATTERN your.tgz
```

Comment: How would i use this to copy found files to another directory?

Comment: I must admit that I haven't read your question carefully. To cp files to a directory, you'll have to uncompress them. I never did that, but I expect that it is possible to uncompress just a couple of files out of an archive using `tar`. `zgrep` will give you the file names (inside the archive)

Comment: I ran the command like this `zgrep "Osaka" 20130619.tar.gz` , returns `Binary file (standard input) matches`

Comment: ok i changed the command to this `zgrep -a "Osaka" 20130619.tar.gz` but i think this returns matched lines, it doesn't return matched filenames. So how would i extract the matched files ,like you alluded to above?